# How can i program this UML class diagram to C# language?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, uml, windows-forms-designer

[image: Automotive Class]

I am confused on how to create  class can you please help me??

```
   class AutomotiveManager
{
    private bool isBeingTested
    {
        set
        {
            isBeingTested= false;
        }
    }

    private dialogResult MessageBoxResult
    {
            ///need help over here
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to turn this into a better question for SO please. This sounds like you're asking us to write the project for you. What specifically do you want to know?

Comment: I got this UML class diagram and was told to program this class in C# Visual studio i am confused on how to program UML classes

Comment: I am not Lazy bone Mr Thomas i m just asking the way to prgram it and better mind your language

Comment: @user3443401 that's too vague though, you'll need to be specific. What part of the UML classes are you not familiar with? I'm sure you know a bit of it. Remember we're not here to write it for you but to help you finish what you've started

Comment: Just on how to prgram dialogresult i have done some work below :        class AutomotiveManager
    {
        private bool isBeingTested
        {
            set
            {
                isBeingTested= false;
            }
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there are a few different issues here.

- The difference between properties and attributes
- The meaning of the `=` in the attributes
- The error (which error?) you get for the declaration of the messageBoxResult

Private `Attributes` are just private Attributes.
So the implementation of a private attribute like the `isBeingTested` would be

```
private bool isBeingTested;
```

The `=` in the attributes means the default value. So that would be the value you assign in the `constructor` or at the declaration of the attribute. For the `isBeingTested` you could add that to the declaration like this:

```
private bool isBeingTested = false;
```

But since in C# the default value for a boolean is false anyway you don't even need to specify it. The way you programmed it you will en up in an infinite loop the moment you try to use the setter for `isBeingTested`

The `«Property»` presumably indicates that you are meant to create a `Property` rather then an `Attribute`, and I guess the `{get;}` indicates that you only need to implement a getter, not a setter for this property. (I'm guessing here since none of that is defined in UML)

The error you are getting is probably because the compiler doesn't know the type `dialogResult`. It may know the type `DialogResult` (notice the uppercase) if you add `System.Windows.Forms` as a reference to your project, and add a using statement like this

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

PS. You also failed to implement the `static` keyword on the class.

Answer (score 1):

To convert your UML class diagram into a C# class, you'll need to understand what each of the symbols represent in your UML class diagram. This image from [tutorialspoint.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/uml/uml_basic_notations.htm) is useful:
[image]

From there, it's a matter of writing the equivalent C# code based on the symbols provided in your example.

Comment: How can i code the messagebox :Dialog result

Comment: Are you referring to the return result of the `ShowMessage()` operation or the `messageBoxResult` attribute?

Comment: i am referring both as i tried to class them but its showing me error